# Method that returns char returns 0

Tags: java

I have a method that should return a char:

```
public char Connect(parameters){
    for (char c : something){
        if (condition){
            return c;
        }
    }
```

As I didn't have a return after the loop, Netbeans added an

```
return 0;
```

at the end of the method. Why? and why its not an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value of `char` type is `'\u0000'`, whose decimal equivalent is `0`. See [JLS §4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5). So, in case the condition in `for` loop never satisfies, the method would return a default value.

> why its not an error?

It shouldn't be an error. Implicit [narrowing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) is going on here from `int` to `char` type.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is a possibility that the flow of control might not reach the if block. If this happens, your code does not specify what to return. Thats why Netbeans added `return 0` for you.

Lets assume that the expression `condition` is never true

```
public char Connect(parameters){
    for (char c : something){
        if (condition){
            return c;
         }
    }
```

The program would then complete the loop, reach end of method, but still wont have anything to return. Thus you can consider `return 0` as a "default" return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that your condition is never satisfied. In this case, if you didn't have a `return` statement, what should be returned ?

The `return 0;` in your case is the default value when the condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

> As I didn't have a return after the loop, Netbeans added an
>
> return 0;
>
> at the end of the method. Why? and why its not an error?

A method declared to have a `return` type can't end normally. It must `return` a value passing any explicit condition. If your `for` loop condition is `false`(which can not be evaluated at compile time) we can't expect it to return from the loop body.

That is why netbean is setting it for you: `0` is default value of `char` and valid return value for a method with `char` return type.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans (probably) added it as a default return value.  This is extremely likely if you had Netbeans auto-generate the method.

It is not an error because 0 can correctly be converted to a character.  See asciitable.com and you'll find that character 0 is a valid character (NUL).